# Ordinary Differencial Equation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, ode

I have spent the last few days looking for ODE solver in Clojure, and need some help.

Specifically, I was hoping to find one that does the same thing as the popular **lsoda()** function in the **R** package **deSolve**. (originally written in Fortran, I believe)

My search has been for either a Clojure library with these capabilities, or a Clojure library with the ability to call the original Fortran version from inside clojure.

I was hoping someone would already have experience on this topic and would be willing to help.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I have very little knowledge of ODEs in general so maybe I am entirely off base. I hope to model planetary orbiting in clojure. In my time with R, I used lsoda() to pass the initial positions and velocities of planets/stars, and ended up with predictions of the planets some amount of time later. Hope this helps explain what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.konato.com/2009/07/08/having-fun-with-ordinary-differential-equations-in-clojure-using-com-konato-ode-part-1/)? Specifically https://github.com/konato/com.konato.ode.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I did look at Konato.ode, but I am not sure if it has what I am looking for. I am trying to model planetary orbits and hope to pass the integrator a vector of positions and velocities, instead of an actual equation.

Comment: It is extremely easy to write your own implementation of your own explicit ODE. I always found it easier to write my own even in Fortran when I could use some libraries. For first order Euler just compute the function and multiply by delta_t. For Runge-Kutta it's the same in multiple steps.

Comment: Erp12, you might want to ask about this on the [Numerical Clojure Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/numerical-clojure).